# Mercurial commit on new repository

Tags: mercurial, bamboo

I have a Bamboo plan that runs a script to build a project.  The script updates the AssemblyInfo.cs files in the solution to the next build number, then commits the change and does a fetch to merge any changes and avoid getting multiple heads.

```
hg commit -m "$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)"
hg fetch
```

The output from Bamboo ends up being:

```
02-Jul-2012 07:50:11 CommitChanges:  
02-Jul-2012 07:50:11 Commiting version number changes for d:\Builds\TDFGE-DRD-JOB1  
02-Jul-2012 07:50:11 hg commit -m "1.0.0.6"  
02-Jul-2012 07:50:12 created new head  
02-Jul-2012 07:50:12 hg fetch  
02-Jul-2012 07:50:12 abort: multiple heads in this branch (use "hg heads ." and "hg merge" to merge) 
02-Jul-2012 07:50:12 d:\Builds\TDFGE-DRD-JOB1\Build.proj(96,3): error MSB3073: The command "hg fetch" exited with code 255. 
02-Jul-2012 07:50:12 Done Building Project "d:\Builds\TDFGE-DRD-JOB1\Build.proj" (UpdateVersionAndBuild target(s)) -- FAILED. 
02-Jul-2012 07:50:12
02-Jul-2012 07:50:12 Build FAILED.
```

The docs for Mercurial says that Fetch should get the latest code and merge any changes.

This seems like a very simple task, change some files, check them in, continue.  So what am I missing here?  Do I need to do a merge or something?  PS.  I did try adding another merge/commit after the original commit (did not seem correct, but it completed), but then the files pushed back to the main repository still had the old version number, i.e. they were unchanged.  Seems like the merge command took the main repository as the primary parent.

Comment: I can run this command localy all day long, no problems, no multiple heads.  The only difference I can think of is that in TortoiceHg Workbench I have the checkbok checked (Automatically resolve merge conflicts where possible) in the Post Pull Behaviour dialog.  Not sure if that makes a difference, but it might.

Comment: Also ran the command locally as the build user in the same folder as where Bamboo runs it and it works.  Does HG act differently when the user is running as a service?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer in the end was not what I was looking for.  Still not sure why HG was having the issues it was having, but it's proably not possible to update and commit version number changes.  My guess is that the reason there's no path back to the main repository for Bamboo deploys is because that would cause another bamboo deploy to start because of the commit and cause an endless loop of builds.

In the end I changed the code to just update the files, build, create the NuGet package and be done.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across the same problem. I believe the reason the commit didn't take is that bamboo has a repository cache on the ci server. The job repository is cloned from the cache repository, therefore any pushes will go to the cache repo and not out to bitbucket.

To get around this issue, I explicitly push to the hosted repo.

hg push https://user:password@bitbucket.org/myrepo